# Scrollbar up button event

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I want to know if in javascript is any event called when we press this scrollbar button?

**Scrollbar up button**

[image]

Comment: check out [onscroll](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp)
and [MDN onscroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll)

Comment: I don't think you can detect **only** this button but not the mouse wheel for example. Anyway you can use [`scroll`](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the specific scroll up/down button. Though you can call a javascript function from the HTML code that reacts on scrolling, either if you scroll up or down.

Or you can make your own scoll button:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollby.asp

W3Schools have a good article:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp